# Escaping .NET regex pattern for javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc

Is there any helper function in (ASP).NET library that properly escapes .NET regex patterns to be used in javascript? So that i don't need manually escape `+` quantifiers, etc. As far as i understand RegularExpressionAttribute from Data Annotations performs proper translation. Can i reuse it somehow?

Comment: I've not used it but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode.aspx may help. Looks like it should take any string from .NET and make it into a valid string in javascript (by escaping stuff, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape() is your friend:

```
string escapedInput = Regex.Escape(input);
```

Turns, for instance, `"a+b"` into `"a\+b"`.